# Accessing dynamically appended div elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I need a suggestion on below scenario.
I have an object of items and dynamically building a html object as follows:

```
$.each(item,function(k, iteminner) {
    html += '<td><div id="outerdiv">' + iteminner.Name + '</div>';
    html += '<div id="clickme"></div></td>';
});
```

A `table` is built in this format, where each box will contain a name and button in each `td`. When a user clicks on a button of a cell I want to show the name respectively.What is it that I am missing here?

```
$('#clickme").click() {
    alert($("#outerdiv").iteminner.name);
}
```

Assuming that id is unique for both the divs, like `id="outerdiv" + k` , how do I access element present in second cell, when second div `id="clickme" + 2` is clicked?

Comment: Id has to be unique.

Comment: change $('#clickme") to correctly use " or '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you are appending multiple elements with the same `id` to the DOM, which is invalid. You should change your HTML to use classes, like this:

```
$.each(item, function(k, iteminner) {
    html += '<td><div class="outerdiv">' + iteminner.Name + '</div><div class="clickme"></div></td>';
});
```

From there you need to use a delegated event handler on the `.clickme` elements (as they are dynamically created after the DOM has loaded) to traverse the DOM and find their sibling `.outerdiv`. Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickme', function() {
    var name = $(this).siblings('.outerdiv').text();
    // do something with name here...
});
```

Note that I used `document` as the primary selector above. Ideally you should use the nearest static parent element - I would suggest you use the same selector you use to append the `html` variable to.

Answer (score 3):

**ID's** they have to **UNIQUE**

```
// Use class instead
$.each(item, function(k, iteminner) {
  html += '<td><div class="outerdiv">' + iteminner.Name + '</div>';
  html += '<div class="clickme"></div></td>';
});


// You need to have event delegation here as a direct onclick wont be binded for the dynamically created .clickme
$(document).on("click", ".clickme", function(){

  // You need to fetch the html of .outerdiv, so traverse to it first.
  var _html = $(this).closest("td").find(".outerdiv").html();
  alert(_html);

});
```